# BIRT Engine Integration In Struts2

Tags: struts2, birt

I am integrating the BIRT Engine with Struts2 following this link http://birtworld.blogspot.com/2010/02/birt-and-struts-2.html at basic level it is ok.
But I am facing following issues...

1. Passing parameter to Task renderer...

   task.setParameterValue("csvFilePath", req.getParameter("csvFilePath"));

   this is thorwing an exception **"The type of parameter "csvFilePath" is expected as

   "string", not "[Ljava.lang.String;"**, I dont know what is mean by **string** here 
   please help in the context.
2. Drill down report has broken link.

   I have two reports report1 and report2. report2 is not coming up when followed the hyperlink in report1.

   The hyperlink seems to be broken, report has this hyperlink **"http://localhost:8080/ReportEngineIntegration/run?__report=%2FE%3A%2FDashboardReportEngine%..."**. I wonder why this happening and why /run? is coming in the ulr.
   Please help me in the context.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

getParameter returns a string array. If a method takes a string, send only one string. (Making some assumptions about what req is here.)

That said, if you're using Struts 2, why are you accessing the request anyway?